# How can graphs be exposed as components and used in NoFlo UI

Tags: noflo

I have some custom NoFlo components and graphs in a NoFlo node.js-based project that I'd like to be able to use in the NoFlo UI.

In the NoFlo UI, I'm able to search for and use the custom components without a problem, but the graphs aren't appearing in the component search.

I looked for examples in the existing NoFlo library projects.  Here are a couple examples of library projects that contain both custom components and graphs.  I installed both into my project, and in both cases I'm able to see the components, but not the graphs in the NoFlo UI:

- [noflo-adapters](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-adapters)
- [noflo-yaml](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-yaml)

Should I be able to use these graphs as components in the UI?  Do I need to expose them some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for this was added quite recently. Can you ensure you're running [noflo-nodejs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/noflo-nodejs) 0.0.5 or newer?

Comment: I'm using noflo-nodejs 0.0.5, and noflo 0.5.0.  I re-installed my node modules and not seeing graph-based components like noflo-adapters PacketsToString in the components search results.

Comment: I've also confirmed that with a clean install of noflo-nodejs I can't use the graphs as components.

Comment: It seems to be working now.  Not sure what changed as I was already using 0.0.5.